# Mercurial: How to merge a repository which is separated from main repository

Tags: merge, mercurial, repository, tortoisehg

First, I have a main repository called 'RepoA'. In this repo, there is a folder called 'components'. 
Then this folder is separated from main repository as a standalone repository which is called 'RepoB' with all the histories. 
Although 'RepoB' is created, the changes in folder 'components' are still pushed in 'RepoA' and 'RepoB' also has little changes pushed.
Now I want 'RepoB' to have all the new changes of folder 'components' in 'RepoA'.
I'm using TortoiseHg, is there any way to make this?

Comment: What do you mean with 'separated from main repository'? Do those repositories share a common first commit (thus are forks of a common ancestor) or are they technically completely unrelated repositories?

Comment: @planetmaker yes, there is only one repository first and then one folder is separated as a repository(I used 'convert' command to finish this).

Answer (score 0):

Convert folder to `RepoC` with the same structure as for `RepoB`, pull `RepoC` from `RepoB`